# how to store data in local storage in angular2

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular2-services

```
login(user) {
    this.loginService.login(user).subscribe((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

In this in response I'm getting:

```
Response {_body: "{"success":{"data":{"displayName":"yash gupta","id…9.Q_jhs4sEA7dOxsdMIG0R5X8U0hW9-5ZekI6kWX265iU"}}}", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}
headers
:
Headers {_headers: Map(1), _normalizedNames: Map(1)}
ok
:
true
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
type
:
2
url
:
"http://localhost:3234/api/login/default"
_body
:
"{"success":{"data":{"displayName":"yash gupta","id":258,"email":"asdasdasd@asdasd.com","role":"admin","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkaXNwbGF5TmFtZSI6Inlhc2ggZ3VwdGEiLCJpZCI6MjU4LCJlbWFpbCI6Inlhc2hAYWtlby5ubyIsInJvbGUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTUxNTU2NjA3NCwiZXhwIjoxNTE1NjUyNDc0LCJhdWQiOiJCdWxsVG9rZW5Vc2VycyIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYnVsbFRva2VuQXBpLmNvbSJ9.Q_jhs4sEA7dOxsdMIG0R5X8U0hW9-5ZekI6kWX265iU"}}}"
__proto__
:
Body
```

I only need to store token in my local storage of browser. Can someone tell me how can I store using set item method.

Comment: You can take a look at this module: https://github.com/zoomsphere/ngx-store and just do `localStorageService.set('token', token)`

Answer (score 1):

Use **HTML 5** LocalStorage,

//Set

```
localStorage.setItem("token", Response.token);
```

//Get

```
let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
```

FYI: If you want to see the stored variable follow these steps(in chrome browser),

1) take developer tool (By clicking F12)

2) Go to Application tab

3) Open Local Storage menu from Storage area

4) Click your site listed

Now you can see your variable name (*token*)